# Is it possible to retrieve a friend's CS:GO match score in JSON using Steam Web API's

Tags: steam-web-api

How to get JSON with friend's match status? [GetPlayerSummaries](https://developer.valvesoftware.com/wiki/Steam_Web_API#GetPlayerSummaries_.28v0002.29) include only name of the game, but how to get actual score of CS:GO match?

Found [this](https://partner.steamgames.com/doc/features/enhancedrichpresence), but can not get it like JSON. On picture dota status (green text), but I need CS:GO match score

[image]